# Nested QTreeview from specified directory and subdirectories

Tags: python, pyside, qtreeview

I'm populating a QTreeview from a specified folder directory. However I'm not entirely clear on how to properly adjust the code to make the Treeview better reflect the nesting of the folders. In this case I only want to show folders that contain OBJ files within them.

[image]

and I want it to looks like this

[image]

```
import os, sys
from Qt import QtGui, QtWidgets, QtCore

class MainWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.resize(350,500)

        self.ui_navigator = QtWidgets.QComboBox()
        self.ui_files = QtWidgets.QTreeView()
        self.ui_files.setHeaderHidden(True)
        self.ui_files.setModel(QtGui.QStandardItemModel())
        self.ui_files.setEditTriggers(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.NoEditTriggers)
        self.ui_files.setSelectionBehavior(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.SelectRows)
        self.ui_files.setSelectionMode(QtWidgets.QAbstractItemView.ExtendedSelection)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.ui_files)
        self.populate_files()


    def populate_files(self, files=[]):
        model = self.ui_files.model()
        model.clear()

        root = 'C:/Users/jmartini/Desktop/Trash/models'

        for subdir, dirs, files in os.walk(root):

            folder_item = QtGui.QStandardItem(os.path.basename(subdir).upper())
            folder_item.setData(subdir, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
            folder_item.setData(QtGui.QColor(QtGui.QColor(200, 140, 70, 255)), role=QtCore.Qt.ForegroundRole)
            fnt = folder_item.font()
            fnt.setBold(True)
            folder_item.setData(fnt, role=QtCore.Qt.FontRole)
            model.appendRow(folder_item)

            for file in files:
                if file.lower().endswith('.obj'):
                    filepath = os.path.join(subdir, file)
                    name = os.path.basename(file)
                    item = QtGui.QStandardItem(name)
                    item.setData(filepath, role=QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                    folder_item.appendRow(item)

        model.sort(0, QtCore.Qt.AscendingOrder)

def main():
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MainWindow()
    ex.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Did my solution work?

Answer (score 2):

Using `QFileInfo` and `QDir`:

```
def populate_files(self):
    model = self.ui_files.model()
    model.clear()
    exts = ["*.obj"]
    root = 'C:/Users/jmartini/Desktop/Trash/models'
    def addItems(parent, path):
        finfo = QtCore.QFileInfo(path)
        if finfo.isFile():
            if "*."+finfo.suffix() in exts:
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(finfo.fileName())
                it.setData(finfo.absoluteFilePath(), QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                parent.appendRow(it)
        elif finfo.isDir():
            iterator = QtCore.QDirIterator(finfo.absoluteFilePath(), exts, QtCore.QDir.Files, QtCore.QDirIterator.Subdirectories)
            if iterator.hasNext():
                it = QtGui.QStandardItem(finfo.fileName().upper())
                it.setData(finfo.absoluteFilePath(), QtCore.Qt.UserRole)
                parent.appendRow(it)
                for subfiles in QtCore.QDir(finfo.absoluteFilePath()).entryInfoList([], QtCore.QDir.AllEntries|QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot):
                    addItems(it, subfiles.absoluteFilePath())

    for finfo in QtCore.QDir(root).entryInfoList([], QtCore.QDir.AllEntries|QtCore.QDir.NoDotAndDotDot):
        addItems(model, finfo.absoluteFilePath())
    self.ui_files.expandAll()
```

[image]